# plot lightning data in Google maps

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I've got a weather website, which misses lightning data.
I found a data source from Blitzortung.org wich contains the Lat, Lon and time info of a lightning strike. How do I get this on Google Maps?

I want the data to be realtime, just like on blitzortung.org.
It should be displayed on the map, preferably as a red or yellow dot, changing color as it ages (probably a JavaScript or PHP function that can edit css to do this) and of course on the right place.

I unfortunately had no experience with JSON and SQL, but don't call me lazy because I don't have the time to really learn this.
I've got the map and the radar overlay which updates every 5 minutes: http://met.nl.eu.org/radar.html

this is the data source: http://www.lightningmaps.org/live/
I can use this source, provided that I will not use it for profit and that I add link to Blitzortung.org

So my main question is, how do I get Google maps to interpret the coords in the JSON file as places on the map, and draw a marker on the place, which changes color as it ages?

server:

Ubuntu with Apache,
SQL databases,
PHP5
and python for image processing

---

Edit: this script might help a bit more:

```
    //
//
//
var maps = {
  0: { "west": -180.0, "east":  180.0, "north":  90.0, "south": -60.0, "projection": 1, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 0, region: 0 },
 10: { "west":  -20.0, "east":   44.0, "north":  71.5, "south":  23.1, "projection": 1, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 2, region: 1 },
 11: { "west":    0.0, "east":   35.0, "north":  71.5, "south":  48.5, "projection": 1, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 1 },
 12: { "west":  -15.0, "east":    7.0, "north":  60.0, "south":  47.0, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 1 },
 13: { "west":  -12.0, "east":   20.0, "north":  56.0, "south":  33.6, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 1 },
 14: { "west":   12.0, "east":   37.0, "north":  48.0, "south":  28.5, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 1 },
 15: { "west":   10.0, "east":   30.0, "north":  56.0, "south":  43.1, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 1 },
 16: { "west":    2.0, "east":   18.0, "north":  55.5, "south":  45.3, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 1 },
 20: { "west":  110.0, "east":  180.0, "north":  10.0, "south": -51.6, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 2, region: 2 },
 21: { "west":  156.0, "east":  186.0, "north": -25.0, "south": -48.8, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 2 },
 22: { "west":  135.0, "east":  159.0, "north": -24.0, "south": -43.8, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 2 },
 30: { "west": -130.0, "east":  -60.0, "north":  62.5, "south":   2.3, "projection": 1, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 2, region: 3 },
 31: { "west": -108.0, "east":  -92.0, "north":  38.0, "south":  24.3, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 3 },
 32: { "west":  -92.0, "east":  -76.0, "north":  36.0, "south":  24.0, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 3 },
 33: { "west":  -85.0, "east":  -70.0, "north":  46.0, "south":  34.5, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 3 },
 34: { "west": -105.0, "east":  -85.0, "north":  50.0, "south":  35.3, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 3 },
 35: { "west": -127.0, "east": -105.0, "north":  45.0, "south":  27.3, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 3 },
 36: { "west":  -86.0, "east":  -60.0, "north":  31.0, "south":   6.4, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 3 },
 40: { "west":   85.0, "east":  155.0, "north":  58.0, "south":  -4.5, "projection": 1, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 2, region: 4 },
 41: { "west":  125.0, "east":  148.0, "north":  46.3, "south":  -5.0, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 4 },
 50: { "west": -102.0, "east":  -22.0, "north":  16.0, "south": -57.0, "projection": 1, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 2, region: 5 },
 51: { "west":  -84.0, "east":  -63.0, "north":  16.0, "south":  28.0, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 5 },
 60: { "west":  -25.0, "east":   60.0, "north":  40.0, "south": -38.5, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 0, "detector_type": 2, region: 6 },
 61: { "west":   14.0, "east":   34.0, "north": -20.0, "south": -37.5, "projection": 0, "width": 925, "height": 925, "strike_type": 1, "detector_type": 1, region: 6 } 
 };

var map = maps [page_0];

var Kreis_green       = new Image();
Kreis_green.src       = "../../Images/Kreis_green.png";
var Kreis_gray        = new Image();
Kreis_gray.src        = "../../Images/Kreis_gray.png";
var D_g               = new Image();
D_g.src               = "../../Images/Antenne_green.png";
var D_r               = new Image();
D_r.src               = "../../Images/Antenne_gray.png";
var S_g               = new Image();
S_g.src               = "../../Images/Lautsprecher_green.png";
var S_r               = new Image();
S_r.src               = "../../Images/Lautsprecher_gray.png";

var audiocnt= 0;
var audiocntmax= 10;
var AudioData= 'data:audio/x-wav;base64,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';
var myAudio = new Array (new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData),
                         new Audio(AudioData) );

var DetectorImages     = new Array(new Image(),new Image(),new Image());
DetectorImages [0].src = "../Images/d00g.png";
DetectorImages [1].src = "../Images/d02g.png";
DetectorImages [2].src = "../Images/d03g.png";

var DetectorImage        = DetectorImages [map ['detector_type']];

var StrokeImages      = new Array(new Image(),new Image(),new Image(),new Image(),new Image(),new Image(),new Image(),new Image());
StrokeImages [0].src  = "../Images/s02.png";
StrokeImages [1].src  = "../Images/s03.png";
StrokeImages [2].src  = "../Images/s04.png";
StrokeImages [3].src  = "../Images/s05.png";
StrokeImages [4].src  = "../Images/s06.png";
StrokeImages [5].src  = "../Images/s07.png";
StrokeImages [6].src  = "../Images/s09.png";
StrokeImages [7].src  = "../Images/s99.png";

var Buffer            = new Image();
var Background        = document.getElementById('lb');
var Canvas            = document.getElementById('Bild_Canvas');
var Context           = Canvas.getContext('2d');
var Delay             = document.getElementById('Delay');
var Strikes           = document.getElementById('Strikes');
var Detectors         = document.getElementById('Detectors');
var Sound             = document.getElementById('Sound');

Delay.innerHTML = 'waiting';

var Type              = 0;
if (parseInt(page_0/10)*10 == page_0) {
  Type= 1; }

var first_Stroke      = 0;
var display_Strikes   = true;
var display_Detectors = false;
var use_Sound         = false;

if (read_Cookie ('displayStrikes') != undefined) {
  display_Strikes = eval(read_Cookie ('displayStrikes')); }
if (read_Cookie ('displayDetectors') != undefined) {
  display_Detectors = eval(read_Cookie ('displayDetectors')); }
if (read_Cookie ('useSound') != undefined) {
  use_Sound = eval(read_Cookie ('useSound')); }

var Server;
try {
    // Mozilla, Opera, Safari sowie Internet Explorer (ab v7)
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
catch(e) {
  try {
    // MS Internet Explorer (ab v6)
    xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  catch(e) {
    try {
      // MS Internet Explorer (ab v5)
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch(e) {
      xmlHttp = null;
      xmlHttp2 = null; } } }

var Stations;
if (xmlHttp) {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if ((xmlHttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlHttp.status == 200)) {
        Stations= eval('(' + xmlHttp.responseText + ')');
        for (var s in Stations) {
          Stations[s][1]= projection_x (map["west"],map["east"],map["width"],Stations[s][1]);
          if (map['projection'] == 0) {
            Stations[s][0]= mercator_y (map["west"],map["east"],map["north"],map["height"],Stations[s][0]); }
          else {
            Stations[s][0]= miller_y (map["west"],map["east"],map["north"],map["height"],Stations[s][0]); } } } }
    xmlHttp.open('GET', '/Data/stations.json', true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

/****************************************************************/
/****************************************************************/
/****************************************************************/

function load()
{
}

setInterval(newBackground,63000);
setInterval(drawStrikes,49);

if (display_Strikes) {
  Strikes.src= Kreis_green.src; }
else {
  Strikes.src= Kreis_gray.src; }
if (display_Detectors) {
  Detectors.src= D_g.src; }
else {
  Detectors.src= D_r.src; }
if (use_Sound) {
  Sound.src= S_g.src; }
else {
  Sound.src= S_r.src; }

var ws;

if ("WebSocket" in window) {

  var rnd;
  try {
    rnd= parseInt (Math.random()*10);
    Delay.innerHTML = 'first try';
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://websocketserver.blitzortung.org:801"+rnd); }
  catch (e) {
    rnd= parseInt (Math.random()*10);
    Delay.innerHTML = 'second try';
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://websocketserver.blitzortung.org:801"+rnd); }

  Delay.innerHTML = 'connected';

  ws.onopen = function()
    {
      var start_time= (Date.now()*1000000)-60000000000;
      ws.send('{"west":'+map['west']+',"east":'+map['east']+',"north":'+map['north']+',"south":'+map['south']+',"time":'+start_time+'}');
    };

  ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
    { 
      var Strikes= eval('('+evt.data+')');

      if ( ('ddelay' in Strikes) &&
           ('lat' in Strikes) &&
           ('lon' in Strikes) &&
           ('sta' in Strikes) &&
           ('dev' in Strikes) ) {

        if ( (map ['west'] <= Strikes ['lon']) &&
             (Strikes ['lon'] <= map ['east']) &&
             (map ['south'] <= Strikes ['lat']) &&
             (Strikes ['lat'] <= map ['north']) ) {
  
          var Image;
          if (map['strike_type'] == 0) {
            Image= StrokeImages[parseInt(Math.random()*6)];
          }
          else if (map['strike_type'] == 1) {
            Image= StrokeImages[6];
          }
          else {
            Image= StrokeImages[7];
          }

          var Detectors = new Array();
          if (display_Detectors) {
            for (var s in Strikes ['sta'][1]) {
              var d=Strikes ['sta'][1][s];
              var Detector = new Array(Stations [d][0],Stations [d][1])
              Detectors.push(Detector);
              if (Detectors.length >= 100) {
                Detector.shift();
              }
            }
          }

          var x= projection_x (map["west"],map["east"],map["width"],Strikes ['lon']);
          var y= projection_y (map["west"],map["east"],map["north"],map["height"],Strikes ['lat'],map['projection']);

          var Datum    = new Date();
          var Time     = Datum.getTime();
          first_Stroke = new Stroke (Context,x,y,Image,Detectors,Strikes ['sta'][0],Time,first_Stroke,Strikes ['dev']);
          if (use_Sound) {
            myAudio [audiocnt++].play();
            if (audiocnt >= audiocntmax) {
              audiocnt= 0;
            }
          }

          Delay.innerHTML = 'Delay: '+Strikes['delay']+' s';
        }
      }
      else if ( ('delay' in Strikes) &&
                ('latitude' in Strikes) &&
                ('longitude' in Strikes) &&
                ('signals_used' in Strikes) &&
                ('deviation' in Strikes) ) {
        if ( (map ['west'] <= Strikes ['longitude']) &&
             (Strikes ['longitude'] <= map ['east']) &&
             (map ['south'] <= Strikes ['latitude']) &&
             (Strikes ['latitude'] <= map ['north']) ) {
  
          var Image;
          if (map['strike_type'] == 0) {
            Image= StrokeImages[parseInt(Math.random()*6)];
          }
          else if (map['strike_type'] == 1) {
            Image= StrokeImages[6];
          }
          else {
            Image= StrokeImages[7];
          }

          var Detectors = new Array();
          if (display_Detectors) {
            for (var s in Strikes ['signals_used']) {
              var d= Strikes ['signals_used'][s];
              var Detector = new Array(Stations [d][0],Stations [d][1])
              Detectors.push(Detector);
              if (Detectors.length >= 1000) {
                Detector.shift();
              }
            }
          }

          var x= projection_x (map["west"],map["east"],map["width"],Strikes ['longitude']);
          var y= projection_y (map["west"],map["east"],map["north"],map["height"],Strikes ['latitude'],map['projection']);

          var Datum    = new Date();
          var Time     = Datum.getTime();
          first_Stroke = new Stroke (Context,x,y,Image,Detectors,0,Time,first_Stroke,Strikes ['deviation']);
          if (use_Sound) {
            myAudio [audiocnt++].play();
            if (audiocnt >= audiocntmax) {
              audiocnt= 0;
            }
          }

          Delay.innerHTML = 'Delay: '+Strikes['delay']+' s';
        }
      }
    };

 ws.onclose = function()
   { 
   };

}
else {
  alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!"); }

function unload()
{
}

function StrikesOnOff()
{
  if (display_Strikes) {
    Strikes.src= Kreis_gray.src;
    display_Strikes= false; }
  else {
    Strikes.src= Kreis_green.src;
    display_Strikes= true; }
  write_Cookie('displayStrikes', display_Strikes, 365);
}

function DetectorsOnOff()
{
  if (display_Detectors) {
    Detectors.src= D_r.src;
    display_Detectors= false; }
  else {
    Detectors.src= D_g.src;
    display_Detectors= true; }
  write_Cookie('displayDetectors', display_Detectors, 365);
}

function SoundOnOff()
{
  if (use_Sound) {
    Sound.src= S_r.src;
    use_Sound= false; }
  else {
    Sound.src= S_g.src;
    use_Sound= true; }
  write_Cookie('useSound', use_Sound, 365);
}

function newBackground()
{
  var Datum    = new Date();
  var Time     = Datum.getTime();
  var t        = Math.ceil(Time/60000);
  Buffer.src= Bild_url+'?t='+String(t++);
  Buffer.onload= function () {
    Canvas.style.backgroundImage= "url(" + this.src + ")";  }
}

function drawStrikes()
{
  var Datum    = new Date();
  var Time     = Datum.getTime();

  Context.clearRect(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height)

  var s = first_Stroke;
  while (s != 0) {
    if (s.Time > Time-600000) {
      s.draw();
      s= s.next; }
    else {
      s.next = 0;
      s = 0; } }
}

function Stroke (Context, x, y, Image, Detectors, st_used, Time, Next, Deviation)
{
  this.Context           = Context;
  this.Context.lineWidth = 1.0;
  this.x                 = parseInt(x);
  this.y                 = parseInt(y);
  this.Image             = Image;
  this.Detectors         = Detectors;
  this.st_used           = st_used;
  this.Time              = Time;
  this.next              = Next;
  this.deviation         = Deviation;
  this.cnt               = 0;
  this.ray_cnt           = 40;
  this.detector_cnt      = 200;
};

Stroke.prototype =
{
  draw:
    function()
    {
      var alpha1= (this.ray_cnt-this.cnt)/10;
      if (alpha1 > 1) {
        alpha1 = 1; }
      var alpha2= alpha1*0.7;

      if (this.cnt < this.detector_cnt) {
        if ((display_Detectors)&&(this.Detectors.length > 0)) {
          for (var i=this.st_used; i<this.Detectors.length; i++) {
            var y = this.Detectors[i][0];
            var x = this.Detectors[i][1];
            if (this.cnt < this.ray_cnt) {
              this.Context.beginPath()
              this.Context.moveTo(this.x,this.y);
              this.Context.lineTo(x,y);
              this.Context.strokeStyle= 'rgba(0,255,128,'+alpha2.toString()+')';
              this.Context.stroke(); }
            this.Context.drawImage(DetectorImage,parseInt(x-DetectorImage.width/2),parseInt(y-DetectorImage.height/2)); }
          for (var i=0; i<this.st_used; i++) {
            var y = this.Detectors[i][0];
            var x = this.Detectors[i][1];
            if (this.cnt < this.ray_cnt) {
              this.Context.beginPath()
              this.Context.moveTo(this.x,this.y);
              this.Context.lineTo(x,y);
              this.Context.strokeStyle= 'rgba(64,192,255,'+alpha2.toString()+')';
              this.Context.stroke(); }
            this.Context.drawImage(DetectorImage,parseInt(x-DetectorImage.width/2),parseInt(y-DetectorImage.height/2)); } }

        if (display_Strikes) {
          this.Context.beginPath();
          this.Context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.cnt,0,2*Math.PI,1);
          this.Context.strokeStyle= 'rgba(255,255,255,'+alpha1.toString()+')';
          this.Context.stroke(); } }

      this.Context.drawImage(this.Image,parseInt(this.x-this.Image.width/2),parseInt(this.y-this.Image.height/2));

      if (this.cnt < this.detector_cnt) {
        this.cnt++; }
    },
}
```

Just ignore the audio part, as I will not need it.

---

Edit: I've changed my needs. The first priority is to get the lightning strikes on the right place. The changing of color and stuff might come in a later point of the development but for now just the data on the map is fine.

Comment: This is not really the kind of question we like on SO because it doesn't show an attempt to do what you are asking for, and without showing some code, we don't know what is your coding experience. Therefore, **your question might get closed**. Also, your question is quite vague and lacks some information. Do you have right to use this data; in other terms, is it public? Will you need to refresh the data on a regular basis? Do you want to import it in your own database? How do you want to display it on your map? etc. Please update your question with more information.

Comment: It's quite hard to proof that i'm trying to make an attempt, because i have absolutly no experience with json and SQL. I googled alot and i downloaded a code that might display the lightning on a map, but i'm not really shure what it does. The things i do know will be ediited in.

Comment: Do you have a map at all? Do you know how to use the API?

Comment: yes, i have the map. I've got the radar overlay and i've got it styled. I'm not that fimiliar with the API but i know how to get images as overlay.

Comment: Anyone who can help me?

Comment: The website doesn't serve jsonp (only json) so you can't fetch it with a simple AJAX request. Instead you will need to read the file server-side on your webserver before you can read the contents (still with AJAX).

Comment: Can ajax also plot the coords on google maps or is there a script that needs to convert the strings to coords in between?

Comment: And does that mean i have to download the data everytime instead of using the external url to Blitzortung? 'Cause my server is just a cubieboard with a 4 gig sd-card and doesn't have that much memory.

Comment: How do i let Javascript read that json file and create map markers. I'm not experienced with javascript or json, and i'm just beginning with google maps. The changing in time may come on a later point, that is not a priority at this point. I already have the map on my website, i just need to visualize the data over the image, kind off like the z-index in css. Thanks already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a PHP script that will open and read the json from the live URL:

File: `get_lightnings.php`

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo file_get_contents("http://www.lightningmaps.org/live/");

?>
```

This will read and echo the json.

2) Query that URL with javascript by using AJAX. Here is an example map script that will query the PHP file with [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and create a marker for each lightning:

```
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "relative/path/to/get_lightnings.php"
    }).done(function (data) {

        data.d.forEach(function (lightning) {

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lightning.lat, lightning.lon),
                map: map,
                title: 'Lightning'
            });
        });
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Below is the **full HTML page** for you can copy it right away and test it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lightnings</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style>
            #map-canvas {
                height: 400px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="map-canvas"></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

                // Query and plot the data once the map is ready
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {

                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "get_lightnings.php"
                    }).done(function(data) {

                        data.d.forEach(function(lightning) {

                            new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lightning.lat, lightning.lon),
                                map: map
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This was tested and is working fine.

Comment: wow, thanks. i'll test it right away and i'll give you some credit in the codes!

Comment: I've got the map, but there's no lightning. http://84.24.134.81/test/radar.html http://84.24.134.81/test/get_lightnings.php

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but it really helped. +1

Comment: I've got a problem loading this into my already styled map. It keeps trhowing me syntax errors sying it misses a { or a variation on that.

Comment: The above code contains no error. Must be a problem in your origin code or how you implemented it. Without seeing your code no-one can tell.

Comment: i got it working. But the data presented by blitzortung is live, can the PHP script make it live too with a http_refresh request?

Comment: You can't be *live*. But you can setup your AJAX call to query the PHP file on a regular basis. But **be careful**: if lightningmaps.org see hundreds of queries from your server IP, they might ban your server IP (you should check that with them) and you should make sure the AJAX request is not cached.

Comment: Oké, thanks. i've got a cronjob running every 2 minutes. And i don't think they mind me "grabbing" their data, as i don't make money of it ( http://forum.blitzortung.org/showthread.php?tid=656&pid=7580#pid7580 )

Comment: cronjob executing the get_lightning.php

Comment: Is there a way to change the icon image with older strikes?

Comment: Why would you execute that file with a cron job? You call this PHP page every time you view the map so you will get the latest data anyway. I don't understand your last question. Replace the icon with what?

Comment: I didn't know that. And the icon, the oldest strikes (time is seen in the json file) a different color than newer strikes.

Comment: Well yes... you can do that. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

Comment: All that the PHP page does is to read the JSON and print it on get_lightnings.php. Nothing else. That way, when you query this page with AJAX, it returns what it on `http://www.lightningmaps.org/live/` so that you can parse the data client side (javascript).

Comment: And the google api knows that when i write something like "if time > 3000 then remove object"